# Mixed DML Operations in Test Methods - system.RunAs(user) - but why?

Tags: apex, unit-test, transaction, runas

Reading the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects_test_methods.htm), the advice is to run certain DML operations within a `System.runAs(user)` block.

I don't really understand why that needs to happen. I know that it works - as my unit test for creating an EmailTemplate is now working. But I don't *really* know why it has to be within a specified user context.

Can someone provide a clearer insight than the documentation as to why this needs to happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow the link to [sObjects That Cannot Be Used Together in DML Operations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects.htm)
 to better understand (emphasis mine):

> DML operations on certain sObjects, sometimes referred to as setup objects, can’t be mixed with DML on other sObjects **in the same transaction**. This restriction exists because some sObjects affect the user’s access to records in the org. You must insert or update these types of sObjects in a different transaction to prevent operations from happening with incorrect access-level permissions. For example, you can’t update an account and a user role in a single transaction. However, deleting a DML operation has no restrictions.

The key with using `system.runAs` is that you create a *separate transaction*, and that enables you to work with both types of `sObject`.